# PHP require_once php path?

Tags: php, apache, phpmailer

[image]

I'm trying to include PHP mailer but getting this error:

[image]

the location of PHP Mailer is:

[image]

and the php.ini file has that as the correct includes path:

[image]

and that php.ini file is the one that PHPInfo() gave me.

What am I missing here?  Did I break PHP?  Was everyone right about PHP all along?  Am I a dupe?

Comment: Have you tried uncommenting the UNIX include path?

Comment: Why are you not using composer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `include_path` is commented out

```
;include_path = ".:/usr/share/php"
^ remove semicolon
```

Comment: I ended up using set_include_path ( '/usr/share/php/'); which worked but I did what you suggested and commented out the above and it still worked.  So maybe that was it :)

Answer (score 3):

Your directory is named `libphp-phpmailer` and in the `require_once` you name it `libphp-PHPMailer` (with upper case letters).

Answer (score 0):

You're using an old version of PHPMailer and you're loading it in the wrong way. Please [get the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and read the docs on loading, or add PHPMailer to your `composer.json`.

For a manual load you should do:

```
require '/path/to/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
```

As you're using composer (though you've commented it out), you don't even need to do that much since the composer autoloader will work.

You've also based your code on an old example, so I suggest you update that too using [one of the examples provided](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples).

Comment: Yup, I was following the Harvard CS50 MOOC example which is likely dated.   I'm also using their ubuntu distro which must have had some of these quirks.  I've since resolved everything.